# Why is migration thinking an entry exist on a recently created table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently trying to add an message column to my table which is modelled to look like this

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string ActionType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElement { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElementType { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public User ForUser { get; set; } = new User();
    public User ByUser { get; set; } = new User();

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public bool Seen { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Clicked { get; set; } = false;

    public Dictionary<string, string>? MessageProperties { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want it to look like this

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string ActionType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElement { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElementType { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public User ForUser { get; set; } = new User();
    public User ByUser { get; set; } = new User();

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public bool Seen { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Clicked { get; set; } = false;

    public Dictionary<string, string>? MessageProperties { get; set; }
    public Message MessageContent { get; set; }
}

public record Message
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string? MessageContent { get; init; }
    public Dictionary<string, string>? MessageContentProperties { get; init; }
}
```

I have via EF managed to make a migrations, but have some issues applying it.

The error message i get when I apply it is

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "Notifications" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Notifications_Message_MessageContentMessageId"
DETAIL:  Key (MessageContentMessageId)=(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) is not present in table "Message".
```

which I am not sure I understand why and how i should fix.

It fails when it tries to do this

```
ALTER TABLE "Notifications" 
ADD COLUMN "MessageContentMessageId" uuid DEFAULT uuid_nil() NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the relationship nullable:

```
public Message? MessageContent { get; set; }
```

It seems that you have nullable reference types enabled so EF Core will consider the relationship required and will try to insert the default `Guid` value.

Read more:

- [Required and optional properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions)

Answer (score 1):

first of all remove default value of `MessageId` and make the `MessageId` property nullable, then change the `Notification` class to use the `MessageId` property from the `Message` class

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string ActionType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElement { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActionElementType { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public User ForUser { get; set; } = new User();
    public User ByUser { get; set; } = new User();

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public bool Seen { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Clicked { get; set; } = false;

    public Dictionary<string, object>? MessageProperties { get; set; }
    public Message? MessageContent { get; set; }
}

public record Message
{
    [Key]
    public Guid? MessageId { get; set; }
    public string? MessageContent { get; init; }
    public Dictionary<string, object>? MessageContentProperties { get; init; }
}
```

now generate a new migration and then apply the migration to update the database like below

```
dotnet ef migrations add UpdateNotificationMessage
dotnet ef database update
```